# Nesting a parent child relationship in lodash, given the parent id and children

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, lodash

How would I be able to nest json object if the parent and its children was given as a property.

The data looks like:

```
   "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "foo",
        "parent": null,
        "root": 1,
        "children": [2, 4, 6],
        "posts":[
            { "id": "1", "name": "item1" },
            { "id": "2", "name": "item2" },
            { "id": "3", "name": "item3" }
        ]
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "bar",
        "parent": 1,
        "root": 1,
        "children": null,
        "posts":[
            { "id": "4", "name": "item4" }
        ]
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "bazz",
        "parent": null,
        "root": 3,
        "children": [5, 7],
        "posts":[
            { "id": "5", "name": "item5" },
            { "id": "6", "name": "item6" }
        ]
    },
   ....
```

A simple groupby using lodash won't do it.

```
var group = _.groupBy(data, 'parent');
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tzugzo8a/1/

The context of question is a nested categories with subcategories, and categories can have categories and posts in them.

Basically I don't want to have a different property for children and posts, since they are all children of a parent.

**Desired output**

```
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "foo",
        "parent": null,
        "root": 1,
        "isCategory": true,
        "children": [
             {
                 "id": 2,
                 "name": "bar",
                 "parent": 1,
                 "root": 1,
                 "isCategory": true,
                 "children": null
             },
             { "id": "1", "name": "item1", isCategory: false },
             { "id": "2", "name": "item2", isCategory: false },
             { "id": "3", "name": "item3", isCategory: false }

        ]
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my take on the question ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grob9u4j/4/)):

```
var data = getData();

var group = getTree(data);

console.log(group);

function getTree(flat) {
    return _.reduce(flat, function (treeObj, item, prop, flatTree) {
        var children = _.map(item.children, function (childId) {
            return _.set(flatTree[childId], 'isCategory', true);
        }).concat(_.map(item.items, function(item) {
            return _.set(item, 'isCategory', false);
        }));

        item.children = !!children.length ? children : null;

        delete item.items;

        item.parent === null && (treeObj[prop] = item);

        return treeObj;
    }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzugzo8a/3/):

```
var data = getData();

_.keys(data).forEach(function(id){
    var element = data[id];
    if (element.children === null){
        element.children = [];
    }

    element.isCategory = true;
    element.items.forEach(function(item){
        item.isCategory = false;
    })
});

_.keys(data).forEach(function(id){
    var element = data[id];
    element.children = element.children.map(function(childId){
      return data[childId];
    }).concat(element.items);
});

_.keys(data).forEach(function(id){
    delete data[id].items;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(_.findWhere(_.values(data), {'parent': null})));
```

Comment: @JoeyHipolito could you be more specific? And how difficult for you to update the solution to the desired output? I think you will benefit yourself working and changing the code instead of blindly copy/pasting